# pman() function from bash in zsh

Tags: macos, bash, profile, zshrc

I've got this neat little function to open man pages in the Preview.app in my bash profile

```
pman() {
    man -t $@ | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app 
}
```

and I want to use it in my zshrc but it doesn't work does anybody know how to fix it? Preview.app still opens but it ask which file to preview and not like in bash which opens the man page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me here in a quick test.  Do you have something else going on in your zshrc that might affect it?  Tip: you can leave the `/Applications` and `.app` parts off and just use `-a Preview`.

Comment: No it does not work, I've tried it in in nearly empty zshrc only my path and this function. I believe it's stuck in the pipe but I am not an expert in Bash or zsh Scripting. By leaving the app part it has no effect

Comment: try starting zsh using `zsh -f`, define the function and then test it. That will ensure an *empty* zsh configuration.

Comment: Yes this works...so I have now to find which configuration file the problem is?